# Multiple Direct Digital Synthesizers (DDS) to Increase Sample Rate

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, high-frequency, microwave, dds

I’m looking to generate a RF signal sampled at around 10 GSPS operating above the 3GHz mark. In order to maximize data throughput, the signal will be modulated at that frequency (rather than mixing in a lower frequency baseband).

I have a working system at around 2.5 GSPS using a single [AD9915](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9915.pdf), the parallel input of which is driven using an FPGA (which defines the desired DDS output for each sample on each clock cycle). The AD9915 allows synchronization of output across multiple ICs with a maximum sample rate of 2.5 GSPS.

I’m looking at the most cost efficient possibilities to get to a sample rate closer to 10 GSPS with at least 12-bit resolution (less is not an option). Firstly I’d be open to any IC which can already do this, I haven’t found one. Secondly I have another proposal to do this which would require a different type of multiplexing IC for which I’m not sure one exists...

The idea is to synchronize multiple AD9915s (supported, P34 of [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9915.pdf)), independently drive their parallel inputs for modulation using an FPGA and then use some kind of very high speed ‘analog multiplexer?’ to sample each AD9915 independently to create a higher resolution output. The theory of operation is shown below, but the question is whether anyone is aware of an IC which can accomplish multiplexing these signals at these speeds while maintaining sync?

**Illustration of Multiplexing Idea to increase sample rate:**

[image: Proposed Multiplexing Solution]

*Note: the above diagram shows using two AD9915s, I’m looking to use **four** but the same theory would apply.*

Notice the the multiplexed output (lower chart) is at twice the resolution of the first due to the multiplexer running at 5 GHZ (GSPS).

I’m open to solutions to get the sample rate up. Perhaps another way to think about this problem is creating an arbitrary waveform generator. Most high-end OEMs seem to use custom silicon, this isn't an option for me due to low volume and a commensurately small budget.

Does anyone know how I could create the combined waveform (in the diagram) reliably at the sample rates specified, or does anyone know of any other solution which would get closer to 10 GSPS?

*Footnote 1: I’m not looking for bench equipment, I’m looking to incorporate this into a relatively small device with control over how it is designed and produced.*

*Footnote 2: I’m aware that the AD9914 can go to 3.5 GSPS, but it only supports synchronization across ICs at 2.5 GSPS, and I’d like to get above 3.5 GSPS.*

Comment: I do not know about the programming of the AD9914 to get them to be synchronized as you show in your first graph. However, the DAC outputs of these chips are current sources, so, when operating into low impedances, they can simply be combined in parallel to get the waveform shown in your second graph.  There is no need for a multiplexer. The currents just add up.

Comment: Thanks user69795. However, adding them would not increase the resolution in the way desired. Yes I'd get a combined waveform, but not the desired one with the higher GSPS. Page 34 of the datasheet describes the synchronization, seems possible. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9915.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you had arranged the digital stuff to be half a sample period off for the two DACs. Then just adding them would get you the kind of waveform you want.

Comment: It's a fair point, I've added a bit more clarification to the question. Thank you!

Comment: You can adjust the sync_in and sync_out delays of the slave devices. This will effectively interleave the samples.

Comment: Thanks Lior Bilia - I'll look into that. What would then be the most effective way of combining the now interleaved signals (e.g. avoid adding them together).

Comment: I agree this feels a step closer, and yet perhaps still suffers from the same fundamental problem of sampling each output at the right time (without combining them).

Comment: What are you trying to do on the architectural level of the device? Perhaps an analog way would be better with a VCO based synthesizers and mixers for modulation?

Comment: What I'm creating is very close to an advanced arbitrary waveform generator (encodes digital data) for a whole range of frequencies below and surpassing 3GHz. I think the downside of using a VCO and a mixer in an analogue fashion is encoding data on the baseband - e.g. if I'm operating at 3GHz I'd like to benefit from the data rates available at 3GHz not that of the base band, and if the baseband is a high freq - I'm kind of back to this problem again.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but the AD9166 can do what you want. It has a high speed DAC going up to 12 GS/s and the NCO can be digitally modulated with I/Q at several GS/s. So the data stream is not that much faster, but you can access higher frequencies through the upconversion.

Alternatively, both Analog Devices and Texas Instruments have high speed DACs at that rate, or you can go RF SoC.